# python filter letters in a string

Tags: python, string, letters

I need a command in python which filters the letters in a string but not deleting them for example:

```
string =raw_input("Enter the string:")
if string.startswith("a") and string.endswith("aaa"):
    print "String accepted"
else: print "String not accepted"
if "ba" in string:
    print "String accepted"
else :
    print "String is not accepted"
```

What should I add to ban other letters except a and b in the string

Comment: @machineyearning the type is `str`; `string` is a standard library module, so it's probably best not to shadow it, but it's not such a big deal.

Comment: @machineyearning: as jonrsharpe has already said, no builtin is being shadowed here

Comment: `string` is not a class, nor a "builtin module". Builtins are those names that you can find in `__builtins__`. Perhaps what you meant to say is that string is a module from the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply replace them with the empty string and check whether there's anything left:

```
string = raw_input("Enter the string:")
if string.replace('a','').replace('b',''):
    print "String not accepted"
else:
    print "String accepted"
```

The original string `string` will not be modified.

Comment: Which in Python 2.x would be better as `string.translate(None, 'ab')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a set , convert your string to a set and check if its a [subset](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.issubset) of a set with only `a` and `b`. Example -

```
s = raw_input("Enter the string:")
validset = set('ab')
if set(s).issubset(validset):
    print "String accepted"
else: 
    print "String not accepted"
```

Demo -

```
>>> s = "abbba"
>>> validset = set(['a','b'])
>>> if set(s).issubset(validset):
...     print "String accepted"
... else: print "String not accepted"
... 
String accepted

>>> s = "abbbac"
>>> if set(s).issubset(validset):
...     print "String accepted"
... else: print "String not accepted"
... 
String not accepted
```

---

Or as indicated in the comments you can use [`set.issuperset()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.issuperset) instead . Example -

```
s = raw_input("Enter the string:")
validset = set('ab')
if validset.issuperset(s):
    print "String accepted"
else: 
    print "String not accepted"
```

Comment: You can also use `validset.issuperset(s)`. This way you don't need to convert `s` to a set.

Comment: What @AndreaCorbellini said - plus `validset = set('ab')` is also an option

Comment: Yes, correct, I have accomodated the comments into the answer. Thanks

Comment: `{'a', 'b'}` is also another option (though `set('ab')` will always be much shorter and easier to type)

Comment: `{'a', 'b'}` wont work in Python 2.6 or lower, so thats why I used something that would work there.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use of regular expressions:

```
import re
my_string = raw_input("Enter the string:")
if re.match('^[ab]+$', my_string):
    print "String accepted"
else :
    print "String is not accepted"
```

This will match strings which contain only the characters `a` and `b`, of non-zero length. If you want to match zero-length strings, use `*` instead of `+`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex to search for letters and combinations you want to filter.

`^((?![abcd]).)*$` will match things that don't contain `a`, `b`, `c` or `d`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. It lets you set multiple letters, symbols, etc

```
valid_char = ['a', 'b']

def validate(s):
    for char in s:
        if char not in valid_char:
            return False
    return True

if validate(input("Enter the string:")):
    print('Sting Accepted')
else:
    print('Sting not Accepted')
```

Comment: I'd recommend using a set for `valid_char` in order to obtain *O(n)* complexity.

Comment: Hmm, never used set before, the answer above does look like a better option